# Two sum of 2 numbers == target

Tags: c++, c++17

> Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>nums = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int target =  7 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size()-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if (nums[i]+nums[j]==target)
            {
                cout << " [ " << i << " ," << j-1 << " ] ";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program I have two errors:

```
Debug Assertion Failed , Expression:vector subscript out of range.
```

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7938E906 (ucrtbased.dll) in problems.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal. ( at line 18 --if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target))
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `for (int j = i + 1; j <= nums.size(); i++)` should be `for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++)` (the last valid index is `nums.size() - 1` and you've incremented `i` instead of `j`.

Comment: Ohh , thanks.Now left only first error

Comment: use .at() instead of [] to see the error more clearly...

Comment: It doesn't work....

Comment: @user11908629 [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes in the second `for` loop in your code:

1. The **condition** part should be `j < nums.size()`.
2. the **increment** operation should be `j++` instead of `i++`.

Also, while printing the final indices, print `j`, instead of `j-1`.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>nums = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int target =  7 ;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nums.size()-1; i++)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++)
        {
            if (nums[i]+nums[j]==target)
            {
                std::cout << " [ " << i << " ," << j << " ] ";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
 [ 1 ,4 ]  [ 2 ,3 ]
```

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x7BCDE906 (ucrtbased.dll) in problems.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal at if..

Comment: I 'm sorry,but i am beginner in programming

Comment: i have also 2 warnings (c4018) Warning C4018  '<': signed/unsigned mismatch at line 11 and 12

Comment: i checked , and it is this error Unhandled exception at 0x7BCDE906 (ucrtbased.dll) in problems.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal. I use VS 2019 . i checked also in c++ online compiler and it is fine.

Comment: Can you try to update the Visual Studio 2019 and reinstall the C++ compiler and then try?

Comment: Please avoid C style casts and use C++ static_cast or appropriate variable types.

Comment: It is working , but why i should convert nums.size into int?

Comment: @user11908629 You shouldn't. Your `for` loops should be `for (std::size_t i = 0; i + 1 < nums.size(); ++i)` and `for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); ++j)`

Comment: using a c style cast to silence a warning is not good, because sometimes it really just silences the warning. If the warning was pointing to a real problem then that problem may be still there (not the case here, but c-style casts are to be avoided in general)

Comment: When `nums.size()` is 0 this will cause a bug `nums.size()-1`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        seen = {}
        for j, num in enumerate(nums):
            i = seen.get(target-num, -1)
            if i != -1:
                return [i, j]
            seen[num] = j
        return [-1, -1]
```